# IE7 position hasLayout bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

HTML Mark up-

```
<div class="module main open" id="widg0">
 <div class="main-head">
   <div class="optionsmod">
    <div class="openClose minify">
      <img src="src">
      </div>
     <div class="close">
      <img src="src">
      </div>
     </div>
   <div class="h3">Search</div>
      </div>
    <div class="main-content">
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.module {margin: 0;}
.optionsmod {
     float: right;
     position: relative;
     }
.minify {
     cursor: pointer;
     height: 16px;
     position: absolute;
     right: 12px;
     top: -2px;
     width: 16px;
     }
.close {
     cursor: pointer;
     height: 10px;
     position: absolute;
     right: -2px;
     top: -2px;
     width: 10px;
     }
```

Now this is the main CSS that is being effected, the `.optionsmod` just doesn't take the hasLayout issue, and it is completely out of whack in IE7. Does anyone see any issues with the CSS and maybe a fix for this? IE8+ FF and Chrome all handle this like they should, IE7 is the only browser giving issues because of hasLayout.

[image]

Comment: could we have a little more information , like how it should be and how it does look like in IE7.

Comment: Can we place images on here? I've never done it, if so I can give you some SS

Comment: i guess you can from the editor. edit your question there's an icon for it, else link it

Comment: @GCyrillus added the image

Comment: okay i have a clue , can include parts of HTML where we see the close button and its html .. hmmm can you make a little page with liveweave.com (i believe it works with IE7 too)

Comment: Yeah I'll make a page, I don't use IE7 lol, I use Chrome and FF, just need to test Cross Browser ;) I'll let you know

Comment: @GCyrillus here is a bin for you http://jsbin.com/irerig/1/edit

Comment: jsbin not avalaible for me under IE8 or 7 . this yes :) http://liveweave.com/hN2Dk2 but i do not see bug showing up ?

Comment: So what would be causing this issue that I show above? The arrow is dynamically inserted per if closed or not.

Comment: The only things i see to turn around has layout is to set height or font-size to zero. Also to make h3 flotting too would help. In IE7 an empty element has 1em height minimum (absolute positionning in IE7 does not reduce the minimale height of 1em...

Comment: You can test if the element actually has layout with alert(id.currentStyle.hasLayout)

Comment: Thanks koningdavid, do I just do that in console, and is id a variable I have to set?

Comment: Testing now, I figured it out ;)

Comment: @koningdavid after some more extensive testing, everything I checked hasLayout=true. So, I was on the testing in IE7 and clicked an element, (closing all elements) and then I opened them and they were in the right position? Why is that.

Comment: @EasyBB You could try to add overflow:hidden to .optionsmod, this could resolve the IE7 bug if you are lucky

Comment: I did do that but it only resulted in the images being hidden.